# When does a Nix path type make it into the Nix store when converted to a string and when not?

Tags: nix, nixos

I have noticed in the past that in `nix`, a `./myfile.txt` path type seems to

- sometimes evaluate to `/home/myuser/mydir/myfile.txt`, and
- sometimes to `/nix/store/55j24v9qwdarikv7kd3lc0pvxdr9r2y8-myfile.txt`.

I would like to understand exactly when which case happens.

This is especially important for files that contains any form of secret information, as all files in `/nix/store` are world-readable by all users on the system.

(When using `nixops`, there's a special "keys" feature for this purpose, see section [Managing keys](https://nixos.org/nixops/manual/#idm140737318306400) in the manual, but I think it's still important when and how this path-to-store-path copying happens in `nix` itself.)

Comment: Relevant gist: [Nix String and Path Concatenation](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/de84aece83f8521d087416fa21e34df4)

Comment: Reason for editing the title: This thread is more specifically about when will files referenced by relative paths get copied to the Nix store. For example, as I just learned, a bare relative path will also get copied to the Nix store if assigned to an environment variable in a Nix expression. For example, `pkgs.mkShell { ...; GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL = ./assets/git.conf; ... }`. (With that said, I've been using this page for reference for a long time now, thanks again!)

Comment: From NixOS Discourse: [When is a path in a Nix expression copied into the Nix store?](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/when-is-a-path-in-a-nix-expression-copied-into-the-nix-store/27052)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

User `clever` on the `#nixos` IRC channel explained:

### When it happens

The expansion into `/nix/store/...` happens **when you use a path inside `${}` string interpolation**, for example `mystring = "cat ${./myfile.txt}`.

**It does not happen when you use the `toString` function**, e.g. `toString ./myfile.txt` will not give you a path pointing into `/nix/store`.

For example:

```hs
toString ./notes.txt == "/home/clever/apps/nixos-installer/installer-gui/notes.txt"
"${./notes.txt}"     == "/nix/store/55j24v9qwdarikv7kd3lc0pvxdr9r2y8-notes.txt"
```

### Why it happens

Nix store paths (programs, data, configuration in `/nix/store`) are supposed to be hermetic and immutable once built.

"Hermetic and immutable" only works well if any files they refer to are also in the Nix store. If, for example, some nginx configuration file included another configuration file at `/home/myuser/`, hermeticity and immutability would be broken. This is why "copying path literals to the nix store" is a sensible default.

### How it happens

The `55j24v9qwdarikv7kd3lc0pvxdr9r2y8` hash part is taken from the contents of the file referenced by the `./path`, so that it changes when the file changes and things that depend on it can rebuild accordingly.

The copying of files into `/nix/store` happens *evaluation* time (e.g. when `nix-instantiate` runs to turn nix expressions into `.drv` files).

To make this possible, every string in `nix` has a "context" that tracks what the string depends on (in practice a list of `.drv` paths behind it).

For example, the string `"/nix/store/rkvwvi007k7w8lp4cc0n10yhlz5xjfmk-hello-2.10"` from the `GNU hello` package has some invisible state, that says it depends on the `hello` derivation. And if that string winds up as the input to stdenv.mkDerivation, the newly made derivation will "magically" depend on the `hello` package being built.

This works even if you mess with the string via `builtins.substring`. See [this code](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/0a97eb6bd7d459de80432a5dbf39daf16647bb8c/src/libexpr/primops.cc#L1644-L1658) of nix for how the context of the longer string is extracted in line 1653, and used as the context for the substring in line 1657.

You can get rid of a string's dependency context using `builtins.unsafeDiscardStringContext`.

### Where it happens in the `nix` code

`${}` interpolation uses [`coerceToString`](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/0a97eb6bd7d459de80432a5dbf39daf16647bb8c/src/libexpr/eval.hh#L170-L175), which has a `bool copyToStore` argument that defaults to `true`:

```cpp
/* String coercion.  Converts strings, paths and derivations to a
   string.  If `coerceMore' is set, also converts nulls, integers,
   booleans and lists to a string.  If `copyToStore' is set,
   referenced paths are copied to the Nix store as a side effect. */
string coerceToString(const Pos & pos, Value & v, PathSet & context,
                      bool coerceMore = false, bool copyToStore = true);
```

It is implemented [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/0a97eb6bd7d459de80432a5dbf39daf16647bb8c/src/libexpr/eval.cc#L1457-L1458), and the check for the interpolated thing being a `./path`, and the copying to `/nix/store`, is happening [just below](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/0a97eb6bd7d459de80432a5dbf39daf16647bb8c/src/libexpr/eval.cc#L1469-L1471):

```cpp
if (v.type == tPath) {
    Path path(canonPath(v.path));
    return copyToStore ? copyPathToStore(context, path) : path;
}
```

`toString` is implemented with [`prim_toString`](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/0a97eb6bd7d459de80432a5dbf39daf16647bb8c/src/libexpr/primops.cc#L1633-L1641), and it passes `false` for the `copyToStore` argument:

```cpp
/* Convert the argument to a string.  Paths are *not* copied to the
   store, so `toString /foo/bar' yields `"/foo/bar"', not
   `"/nix/store/whatever..."'. */
static void prim_toString(EvalState & state, const Pos & pos, Value * * args, Value & v)
{
    PathSet context;
    string s = state.coerceToString(pos, *args[0], context, true, false);
    mkString(v, s, context);
}
```

Comment: "The copying of files into /nix/store happens at the time of nix-instantiate; the evaluation of nix expressions is still purely functional (no copying around happens at evaluation time)," I don't think this is correct. Interpolating a path in the repl like `nix-repl> "${./foo.txt}"` will copy the file into the store. They seem to be copied at evaluation time https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/values.html#type-path

Comment: @danidiaz You are right, reading this part 6 years later, that part doesn't make sense. Also, me writing `instantiation ("building")`, doesn't make sense. I will fix it.